# Why am I getting an error when I try to create a for loop for fs.readdir in node js?

Tags: node.js

The following is a snippet of my code. I am attempting to create an array called photoarray that will hold arrays for each directory containing all files for each directory. However, when I run this, I am getting an error. When I run this without a for loop and hardcode directoriesparsed as directoriesparsed[0], it is working correctly. Please help, thanks.

```
var photoarray = [];
for(z=0; z<directoriesparsed.length; z++){
     var Name = [];
     var d = "../public/images/Accepted/" + directoriesparsed[z];
     console.log(d);
     fs.readdir(d, function (err, files) {
         if (err) {
             throw err;
         }
         files.map(function (file) {
             return path.join(d, file);
         }).filter(function (file) {
             return fs.statSync(file).isFile();
         }).forEach(function (file) {
             console.log(file);
             Name.push(file);
             console.log(Name);
         });
         photoarray.push(Name);
         console.log(photoarray);
     });
 }
```

> ```
> fs.js:981 return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
> ^ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '../public/images/Accepted/Scott/duncan1.jpg'
>     at Error (native) at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:981:18)
>     at /home/pi/Node/webserverproject/myapp/backendfiles/testingjson2.js:56:25
>     at Array.filter (native)
>     at /home/pi/Node/webserverproject/myapp/backendfiles/testingjson2.js:55:13
>     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:117:15)
> ```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Any stack trace to go with that error? What's stored in directoriesparsed? Just path strings?

Comment: directories parsed contains: 
[ 'Duncan', 'Emily', 'Scott' ]

Comment: and the error I am getting is:                                fs.js:981
  return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '../public/images/Accepted/Scott/duncan1.jpg'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:981:18)
    at /home/pi/Node/webserverproject/myapp/backendfiles/testingjson2.js:56:25
    at Array.filter (native)
    at /home/pi/Node/webserverproject/myapp/backendfiles/testingjson2.js:55:13
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:117:15)

Comment: Did you double check that the file path is correct? Looks like its looking in `/home/pi/Node/webserverproject/myapp/public/images/Accepted/Scott/duncan1.jpg`

Comment: `return fs.statSync(file).isFile();` is throwing an exception because the path does not exist. Perhaps you want to wrap it in a try/catch block or something to handle such cases?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is correct..this is what the output was when I did console.log(d) in the beginning of my code:     [ 'Duncan', 'Emily', 'Scott' ]
    ../public/images/Accepted/Duncan
    ../public/images/Accepted/Emily
    ../public/images/Accepted/Scott

Comment: What I'm confused about is that it is working perfectly without the loop and then when I add the loop it throws this error. It doesn't make sense to me due to the fact that doing console.log(d) has the above output.